# Render is black

Tags: rendering

For some strange reason, my renders are black and I can't see anything. But if I set the viewport display to Rendered, I can see everything. All the objects, textures and lights, but no in the actual render. I've tried deleting the camera and adding a new one but nothing seems to work.

What's causing this?

Comment: If you are using nodes, check to see if there is something connected to the input of the composite node. No input would lead to a black render.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=render%20black